# C# winforms app thread synchronization

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization

I am very much a beginner in programming and I am wondering about synchronizing threads.

I have a WinForms program that needs to creates threads for each cpu core and run a method a specified amount of times.

I have the threads set up and running in a nested loop but my output is along the lines of;

```
thread: 0, run: 1, time: xxx
thread: 1, run: 1, time: xxx
thread: 2, run: 1, time: xxx
thread: 3, run: 1, time: xxx
thread: 1, run: 2, time: xxx
thread: 2, run: 2, time: xxx
```

etc. However I want the output to display the data like so:

```
thread: 0, run: 1, time: xxx
thread: 0, run: 2, time: xxx
thread: 0, run: 3, time: xxx
thread: 1, run: 1, time: xxx
thread: 1, run: 2, time: xxx
thread: 1, run: 3, time: xxx
```

etc.

In my form I create the threads and call a method from a separate class like so;

```
SomeClass[] thisArray = new SomeClass[numThreads];

for (int runNumber = 1; runNumber <= numberOfRuns; runNumber++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++)
        {
            thisArray[i].mThread = new Thread(thisArray[i].StartMethod);
            thisArray[i].mThread.Start();
            thisArray[i].mThread.Join();


           //Display thread id and number of runs
           this.tBoxW.AppendText(string.Format("") + Environment.NewLine);
           this.tBoxW.AppendText(string.Format("Thread Id: ") + i.ToString() + 
           Environment.NewLine);

           this.tBoxW.AppendText(string.Format("Number of Runs {0}", numberOfRuns) + 
           Environment.NewLine);

        }
}
```

SomeClass is in SomeClass.cs and provides the StartMethod() method which runs through a series of equations.

In order to get the output the way I want, am I right in assuming I need to synchronize the threads? or perhaps there is an easier way of doing it?

As I am just starting out with threading I am looking for the easiest way to achieve the desired output.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

Comment: Starting a thread and then calling Join() is pointless.  You might as well call StartMethod() directly.  Only Join() outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you Hans I shall try this

Comment: @Hans Passant: yes, that basically makes his solution serial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear to me what you want. You have to tell us more what synchronization your problem needs. How the thread tasks depend on each other? If they depend, you have to synchronize. In the end you have to synchronize anyway.

Since it's a WinForms I'm not sure it is possible (whether you tied to an older .NET version), but try to use the newer Task API. Then you can WaitAny(). Or it's even better if you can convert your problem to parallel loop.

Also, you are talking about CPU cores. You won't be able to explicitly assign threads to certain CPU cores (maybe it's not even advised 99% of the time). The thread pool will take care of that. You may want to spawn more thread than CPUs if you need to top off all your CPU resources.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Csaba, I am not concerned with which type of synchronization is used, but am I right in thinking that monitor has less overhead than a traditional mutex or semaphore? The program is using the .net 4.0 framework. I'll look into the Task API and see if I can do anything. I really just want the output to display each threads run one at a time, rather than displaying the information as soon as a run is complete, regardless of which thread it is.

Comment: Ok, so you want concurrency, but you want to see a sorted output. In this case you have to gather the output, sort it for yourself and display it. If you want to display it only at the end, it is easier. If you want to display it sorted in the output, then that's less trivial. You need to keep track of the tasks outputs, and if there's a gap, you have to hold onto the outputting until the gaps are filled. That's what VS2012's "Build Order" output does. There's parallel build system behind VS2012, the output can be mixed up. Build Order displays it in order, but that can cause "output bursts"

Comment: Thanks again Csaba, I only needed to display the output at the end so I took your advice and I was able to sort the output by creating an array of list objects. It's not pretty, but damn it, it works!